# Javascript: How can I loop through a word and slice off the characters after the first vowel?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function that loops through a word, identifies the first vowel found (if any) in the word, and then splits up the word after the vowel.

example input: 'super'
example output: 'su', 'per'

```
function consAy(word){
    if(word[i].indexOf("a" >= 0) || word[i].indexOf("e" >= 0) || word[i].indexOf("i" >= 0) || word[i].indexOf("o" >= 0) || word[i].indexOf("u" >= 0)){

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example input and the corresponding desired output. This seems like something that could be done pretty easily with a regex-based `.replace()`, but it's not clear what result you want.

Comment: @nnnnnn OK, edited. Thanks.

Comment: First you'll want to fix the spelling mistake and change every `word[i].indexOf("…" >= 0)` into `word[i].indexOf("…") >= 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use a regular expression to `.match()` the pattern you are looking for:

```js
function consAy(word){
  var result = word.match(/^([^aeiou]*[aeiou])(.+)$/i)
  return result ? result.slice(1) : [word]
}

console.log( consAy('super') )
console.log( consAy('AMAZING') )
console.log( consAy('hi') )
console.log( consAy('why') )
```

The function I've shown returns an array. If there was a vowel that was *not* at the end then the array has two elements. If there was only a vowel at the end, or no vowel, then the array has one element that is the same as the input string.

A brief breakdown of the regex `/^([^aeiou]*[aeiou])(.+)$/i`:

```
^           // beginning of string
[^aeiou]*   // match zero or more non-vowels
[aeiou]     // match any vowel
.+          // match one or more of any character
$           // end of string
```

...where the parentheses are used to create capturing groups for the two parts of the string we want to separate, and the `i` after the `/` makes it case insensitive.

The `.match()` method returns `null` if there was no match, so that's what the ternary `?:` expression is for. You can tweak that part if you want a different return value for the case where there was no match.

**EDIT:** I was asked for a non-regex solution. Here's one:

```js
function consAy(word){
  // loop from first to second-last character - don't bother testing the last
  // character, because even if it's a vowel there are no letters after it
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length - 1; i++) {
    if ('aeiou'.indexOf(word[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
      return [word.slice(0, i + 1), word.slice(i + 1)]
    }
  }
  return [word]
}

console.log( consAy('super') )
console.log( consAy('AMAZING') )
console.log( consAy('hi') )
console.log( consAy('why') )
```

Comment: Thanks, regex is very confusing to me. Do you know how to do it without regex?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do this. I've updated my answer with a non-regex solution. But I suggest you take the opportunity to learn a little about regex, given that the one I've used is not very complicated and I did explain it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes a reasonably modern browser, or Node.

```
const string = "FGHIJK";

const isVowel = c => c.match(/[AEIOU]/i);
const pos = [...string].findIndex(isVowel);
const truncatedString = `${[...string].slice(0, pos + 1)}`;

truncatedString; // "FGHI"
```

---

### Edit

As has been pointed out, the above is significantly more hassle than it's worth. Without further ado, a much saner approach.

```
const string = "FGHIJK";
const vowels = /[aeiou]/i;

const truncateAfter = (string, marker) => {
  const pos = string.search(marker);
  const inString = pos >= 0;
  return string.slice(0, inString ? pos : string.length);
};

const truncated = truncateAfter(string, vowels);
```

---

Without using a RegEx of any kind. Ye ole fashioned algorithm.

```
const truncateAfter = (string, markers) => {
  let c = "";
  let buffer = "";
  for (let i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i += 1) {
    c = string[i];
    buffer += c;
    if (markers.includes(c)) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return buffer;
};

const truncatedString = truncateAfter(
  "XYZABC",
  ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"],
);
```

---

With RegEx golf.

```
const string = "BCDEFG";
const truncatedString = string.replace(/([aeiou]).*/i, "$1");
```

---

With a reduction.

```
const isVowel = c => /[aeiou]/i.test(c);
const last = str => str[str.length - 1];

const truncatedString = [...string].reduce((buffer, c) =>
  isVowel(last(buffer)) ? buffer : buffer + c, "");
```

---

Via a dirty filter hack, that takes way too much power O(n**2).

```
const truncatedString = [...string]
  .filter((_, i, arr) => i <= arr.search(/[aeiou]/i));
```

---

There are others, but I think that's enough to shake the cobwebs out of my brain, for now.

Comment: Why don't you simply [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) for the regex instead of using all that horribly complicated array/iterator/spread stuff? Also, strings do have a [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) as well, no need to make an array and stringify that using a template literal.

Comment: Wow. Yeah; my brain is off.
Way too much time solving problems that are very scary.

Update forthcoming.

Comment: @bergi I was contemplating a bogo-splice that randomly selected i, and if it was after the first vowel instance, would splice it out, while there were characters after the first instance of a vowel.

...but I've decided that Doc Martin is totally winning my attention over possibly-infinite loops.

Comment: I love that `=> i <=` :-D

Comment: Thought you might. I wanted to put that line in blinking neon lights.

Answer (score 0):

I always like to take opportunities to write incomprehensible array-based code, so with that in mind...

```js
    const regexMatcher = pattern => input => {
        return input.match(pattern)
    };
    
    const splitAtFirstMatch = matcher => arrayLike => {
        return [...arrayLike]
        .reduce(([pre, post, matchFound], element) => {
            const addPre = matchFound || matcher(element);
            return [
                matchFound ? pre :[...pre, element],
                matchFound ? [...post, element] : post,
                addPre
            ];
        }, [[],[], false])
        .slice(0, 2)
        .map(resultArrays => resultArrays.join(''));
    };
    
    console.log(splitAtFirstMatch(regexMatcher(/[aeiou]/))('super'));
```

Comment: Well yes, that's certainly incomprehensible. Why not at least put `vowelFound` in the accumulator as well?

Comment: Excellent point.  I thought the least intuitive way of doing this would be to make result a mixed array with an element representing vowelFound that we slice off afterwards, so I did that.

Comment: Thanks :-) You also might want to use destructuring instead of referring to `result` by index every time

Comment: I meant more like `([pre, post, vowelFound], letter) => { …; return [pre, post, vowelFound || isVowel(letter)]; }`. How's that?

Comment: Of course.  The `.push`es were also annoying me so I replaced them.

Comment: Finally, it wasn't quite re-usable enough for me, so I decided to make it more generic and allow plugging alternative matching methods in.

Comment: As this is unlikely to help anyone I'll delete it when I wake up tomorrow.

Comment: It's quite nice actually :-)